# Different Response code- Inside test Not Acceptable status

Tags: json, unit-testing, http, spring-mvc

What is wrong with test cases??

I have following code:

```
@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public ModelMap register(@RequestBody @Valid User user, Locale locale, BindingResult result) {

    logger.info("Register");
    logger.info(user.getMail());
    logger.info("usern " + user.getUsername());
    logger.info("Result " + result.hasErrors());

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        final Set<String> fieldsName = getErrorFieldsName(result);

        throw new RegistrationException(fieldsName);
    }

    if (!isValidateMail(user.getMail()))
        throw new RegistrationException(Collections.singleton("mail"));

    final UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    userRepo.saveUser(escapeUser(user, id));

    return new ModelMap("msg", "You are registered correct!");
}
```

When I call this controller via `REST Client` like:

`POST`
Request headers

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/json 
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: pl,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
Cookie: JSESSIONID=yS__d1a5V8UOD6pF7qAeXfGmhfsacde
```

With Body:

```
  {
"mail":"alddajdf@mad_kta.com",
"username":"User",
"password":"qwerdty123"
}
```

I receive response Code `200` with following header:

```
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow 1
Server: Wildfly 8 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Content-Type: application/json 
Date: Thu, 10 Apr 2014 16:27:42 GMT
```

But inside test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml")
public class RegisterAccountContrTest {
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@Autowired
protected WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
private RegisterAccountContr contr;

@Before
public void init() {

    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
}

@Test
public void testRegister() throws Exception {

final String s;
s = "{\n" +
        "\"mail\":\"alddajdf@mad_kta.com\",\n" +
        "\"username\":\"User\",\n" +
        "\"password\":\"qwerty123\"\n" +
        "}";

mockMvc.perform(post("/register").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(s)).andExpect(status().isOk());

}
```

Generate Response Code:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :406
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simple, I miss `.json` suffix required by `ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean`. Correct url should look like: `/register.json`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the `MockMvcRequestBuilder`  adds an `Accept` header implicitly if you don't specify any. You should add one

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/register")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(s))
   .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: Sory, it don't solve my problem. Response still have status `406`.